# Couldn't send SMS from Activity , says "could not start conversation"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, smsmanager

This code was working, it opens the default SMS app and message appears in textbox , ready to enter number and send, But now this code doesn't work from Above marshmallow.

**but now It does not work if the default app is Messaging**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + mphoneno);
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
it.putExtra("sms_body", message);
mActivity.startActivity(it);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below method to open default messaging app

```
public void sendSMS()  {  
     String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS  
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));  
 }
```